# Cannot transfer video from Sony HDR-AZ1 to iOS device via the CameraRemoteAPI

Tags: ios, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

We are developing an application to record short video snippets with the HDR-AZ1 and so far can only transfer images.  We also need to transfer the mp4 files, but cannot find the documentation to perform this task.  Has any one implemented a solution for transferring video from the HDR-AZ1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation in Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.00.pdf on Pages 18 and 20.  These describe the APIs necessary to transfer video files.